# Displaying values in numerical order

Tags: java

Say I've used user for for 4 values, and I want to display those values from least to greatest.

Is there a simpler way than doing:

- if a>b>c>d system.out.print a,b,c,d,
- else if a>c>b>d, system.out.print ac,b,d, etc etc

Comment: You can use a sort, either a sort built into the language or one your write. An insertion sort will be fine if you're sure you'll never need to sort more than 4 items.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, what you have as your example probably *is* the fastest, if you really do only have four variables. It isn’t going to be the simplest to read, however.

In a situation like, this, first, I’ll make sure those four values shouldn’t already be in an array. If they’re comparable such that their values can be compared and listed in order, they’re probably better suited as an array, either a simple list of values or a hash map where the variable’s name becomes the key to get the value.

That is, if the real data is something like:

```
fred = 9;
wilma = 3;
barney = 6;
betty = 4;
```

The hashmap would be something like (assuming you’re using Java):

```
hash.put("fred", 9);
hash.put("wilma", 3);
hash.put("barney", 6);
hash.put("betty", 4);
```

However, if the variables need to remain as separate variables, then I’d probably temporarily convert them to a simple array on the fly, sort that array using `Arrays.sort()`, and print out the sorted array, possibly using `StringUtils.join` to put a comma between them.

Answer (score 0):

The `Arrays` class has a built in sort method for this kind of problem.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] values = new int[4];

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 4 values");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Value %d: ", i + 1);
        values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    // Sort the array
    Arrays.sort(values);

    // Display the sorted array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Results:

```
Enter 4 values
Value 1: 57
Value 2: 43
Value 3: 2
Value 4: 23
[2, 23, 43, 57]
```